# Colouring the plane based on nearest point

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have `N` `(x, y)` points on plane, `i-th` point having colour `i`

I need to colour the plane based on nearest point's colour.

I suppose final colours could be represented as polygons with vertices in points of equal distance from multiple initial points.

Have no idea how to approach it. My thoughts so far: points in the middle of two points (where there are no other points with smaller distance) will be on the resulting polygons, but then we need to find equidistant points inside empty space to built the rest of resulting polygons.

Comment: The thing to google is "voronoi diagram"

Comment: @MattTimmermans - learned something new today. Thanks